# SUM query for JSON values in JSON array

Tags: json, sql-server

I need a query to sum values from the json array. Can I do this with sql queries?

Here is my sample json in data column whose type is `nvarchar(max)`;

```
[{"V":0.1,"T":"07.01.2020 00:10:26"}, {"V":0.2,"T":"07.01.2020 00:10:36"}]
```

Expected Output Column
V = 0.3

I tried this query but result is null.

```
SELECT top(1) 
  SUM(CAST(JSON_QUERY(column_name,'$.V') as float)) AS V
  
FROM [Pmd].Trend
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an additional `APPLY` operator and a `OPENJSON()` call with explicit schema (the `WITH` clause):

Table:

```
SELECT *
INTO Trend
FROM (VALUES 
   (N'[{"V":0.1,"T":"07.01.2020 00:10:26"}, {"V":0.2,"T":"07.01.2020 00:10:36"}]')
) v (JsonColumn)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM Trend t
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT SUM(V) AS V
   FROM OPENJSON(t.JsonColumn) WITH (V numeric(5, 1) '$.V') 
) j
```

Result:

```
JsonColumn                                                                 V
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[{"V":0.1,"T":"07.01.2020 00:10:26"}, {"V":0.2,"T":"07.01.2020 00:10:36"}] 0.3
```

As an additional option - an approach, using `JSON_VALUE()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Trend t
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT SUM(TRY_CONVERT(numeric(5, 1), JSON_VALUE([value], '$.V'))) AS V
   FROM OPENJSON(t.JsonColumn)
) j
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.

Comment: @UğurCan You need SQL Server 2016+ to use the built-in JSON support. This error is typical for versions before 2016. What is the current version or what is the compatibility level of the current database?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64)   Apr 29 2016 23:23:58   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: @UğurCan What is the compatibility level (`select name, compatibility_level from sys.databases where name = N'yourdatabase'`)?

Comment: it looks level 120.

Comment: @UğurCan It must be at least 130 to use the JSON built-in support.

Comment: I upgraded it from DB Properties 120 to 130 and it worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: How we can do it in oracle sql?